# Static Qt Build Cryptic Error

Tags: qt, build, makefile, g++, mingw32

I am trying to do a static build of Qt (4.8.1) using mingw32-make (gcc 4.7.0) so that I can statically link my application for the sake of ease of use/delivery.

I keep getting a strange error from mingw32-make, though, which I do not understand.

```
../3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/runtime/JSGlobalObject.h:270:103: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
Makefile.Release:2033: recipe for target 'obj/release/JSBase.o' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [obj/release/JSBase.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/StaticQt/qt/src/script'
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/StaticQt/qt/src/script'
Makefile:1360: recipe for target 'sub-script-sub_src_target_ordered' failed
mingw32-make: *** [sub-script-sub_src_target_ordered] Error 2
```

Looking in the associated Makefile.Release file, on the indicated lines, I find these:

```
Makefile.Release 2033: $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o obj/release/JSBase.o ../3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/API/JSBase.cpp
Makefile.Release 1360: $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o obj/release/pcre_compile.o ../3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/pcre/pcre_compile.cpp
Makefile 34: $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release
```

I really understand very little about makefiles, so haven't a clue what these lines mean. Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: it just occured to me it may be useful for people to know the commandline arguments I used... Well, I followed this guide: http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building_static_Qt_on_Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were syntax errors in the code for some reason. Somebody must've updated the Qt Git with the wrong code just before I downloaded it. I got the code from elsewhere and managed to get it to compile using visual studio's nmake instead... turned out it didn't really matter whether I used mingw or vc2008.